# how can I disable a table row having check box and html links?

Tags: html, css

I have a check box, href links of images, And I am taking the data from database. I want to disable the whole row of some user. How can I achieve this? I have attached code and image of the table. I need to disable whole tr including checkbox, edit and delete button.

```
<form method="post" id="activeinactive" action="activeInactive.php" onsubmit="return ConfirmActiveInactive()">
    <?php
        if($no_of_users>1){
            echo '
                <table class="paginated table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Active</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';

                while($userdetails = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<tr id="disableuser">';
                    echo '<td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">';

                    if($userdetails['is_active']==true){
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="'.$userdetails['member_id'].'" checked=checked disabled>
                              <label></label>';
                    }
                    echo '</span>
                        </td>';

                    echo '<td>'.$userdetails['username'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['email'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['address'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['phone'].'</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" class="not-active"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="" class="delete" name="delete" data-toggle="modal" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete()"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                echo '</tbody>
            </table>';
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Hedge Kindly Share Code of the Relevant Section to Modify. Thank You

Comment: I have edited the question @Hamadkhan

Comment: If you want client-side help - with HTML and CSS - please share the ([mcve]) code that the client sees.

Comment: Besides, please give precision on disabling: Disabling only regarding the checkbox or also disabling actions like delete and edit?

Comment: You can use css. Set `pointer-events: none` on the row (`tr`). Sure user could pass it, but he can do this with attribute `disabled` too.